# Adding transient objects automatically to session using SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy with the ORM mapper.

Say I have an `Url` class which points to a `DomainName` class like this:

```
class Url(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = db.Column(db.String(2083))    
    domain_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("domain_name.id"))
    domain_name = db.relationship("DomainName")
```

In my experience it seems that if I create both an `Url` and a `DomainName` it is sufficient to add one to a session and commit and the other is also persisted to the DB. Something like:

```
domain = DomainName("www.stackoverflow.com")
url = Url("/questions/ask", domain)
session.add(url)
session.commit(url)
```

It seems that using this approach one could save some lines of code, especially in situations where creating an object would require creating a small graph of related objects.

In fact, even this example could have been simplified by creating the DomainName object inside of the `Url` constructor instead of creating it outside, and passing it as an argument to the `Url` constructor.

But is this a good practice? Or is it better to individually add every object to the session?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: the documentation confirms that adding one object to a session, will add the other related through cascading: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects